# getting input to fill a list using loops

Tags: python, loops

hey guys i am trying to create a simple python program where i ask a user to enter numbers and i store it in a list and when the user is done inputting i print out the largest value that the user entered. so far i have

```
my_list=[]
value=input("Enter a value")
while value!=0:
    my_list+=[value]
    value=input()
    print my_list
print max(my_list)
```

But the problem here is that I can't think of how to end the loop without saying value!=0. so if the user enters 0 as an integer my code stops. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Your loop exits when the user types in 0. Is that not what you want to happen?

Comment: `raw_input("Enter a value (or 'end' to end): ")`?

Comment: but what if the user enters wants to see which is the largest among these numbers 1, 2, 4, 0, 7     in this case my program will exit when the user enters 0 and the number after that will not be entered

Comment: if i want the loop to stop when the user types end do i just go while value!=end:  when i do that it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

```
list(iter(lambda:raw_input("Enter A Value(or enter to quit):"),""))
```

is a fun way (if you are using python 2)  (using `input` in python2x is generally a bad idea, it is better to use `raw_input`)

Comment: hmm i have not used iter b4. I am going to have to search it up and see what it does. thanks